# Relations and logic

Tags: logic, relations

$R$ is a relation defined on the set $\mathbb Z$ of integers.

For any $a,b \in \mathbb Z$, $a\,R\,b$ iff for any prime number $p$,one has $p\,|\,a$ if and only if $p\,|\,b$.

I'm trying to prove or disprove if $R$ is reflexive, symmetric, transitive and anti-symmetric, but I'm having problems understand the question. Is the question saying that all prime numbers must divide a and b for there to be a relation $aRb$ in the first place, or just the existence of one? For instance, do i have a relation $2\, R\, 4$ because $2$ is a prime number that divides both a and  b? If so, what's the difference between this question and

For any $a,b \in \mathbb Z$, $a\,R\,b$ iff there exists a prime number $p$ such that $p\,|\,a$ and $p\,|\,b$?

Comment: Suppose $a\ R\ b$. It means if there is a prime which divides $a$ then it must divide $b$ and vice versa.Hence $2R4$ because only prime divisors of $2$ are $-2,2$ which are also the only prime divisors of $4$.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are "related" when a prime $p$ divides both or none : $p\,|\,a$ if and only if $p\,|\,b$, for any $p$. This does not mean that all prime $p$ must divide $a$ and $b$ : there are *infinite* many primes !

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That was what i was thinking: But when we say $a$ and $b$ are related when a prime $p$ divides both or none, is the prime $p$ fixed?

Comment: No; it means that they must have the same prime factors : $6$ and $36$ are related, because both are divided by $2$ and $3$ and only by them, i.e. : for all prime $p$, $p | 6 \leftrightarrow p|36$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Okay, with this i concluded that the relation $R$ is reflexive and symmetric, but is not transitive and not anti-symmetric. Could you help me verify if I'm right? I'm not so sure about the transitivity though. I think $R$ might be transitive.

Comment: Why not transitive ?

Comment: In other words: $a \mathbf R b$ If there exists a prime which divides $a$ then it must divide $b$ and if there exists a prime which divides $b$ then it must divide $a$ too.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Okay $R$ is transitive. Because if $aRb$, then $a$ and $b$ have the same primes that divides them, and so $bRc$ implies that $c$ also have the same primes that divides them. So $aRc$. Is this correct?